# How to wait for an api request to return a response?

Tags: java, rest

We use a proprietary framework based on the rest assured library & Testng to automate API testing for our REST web services. I saw some api testing code which uses `Thread.sleep(n seconds)` to wait for a response to be returned. This seems wrong to me because the response times can vary. I believe that there should be a better way to wait for a response, i.e. wait only as much as necessary. Maybe I could poll every few milliseconds, or use an observer (test)-observed (api) design pattern, or something else. I am not sure.

How do I wait for an api to return a response ?

This is what the code looks like:

```
@Test
public void doApiTesting() throws Exception 
{   
    framework.loginUser(User);
    framework.createNewData();//Takes some time.
    Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
framework.createNewData();//Takes some time.
```

- If you can refactor `createNewData()`, you should: just don't return till you are done with the data creation process. The name doesn't indicate that the call is *merely* to start the data creation process, and thus some programmer somewhere using your APIs may end up spending a lot of time debugging issues caused by code that assumes that the data is present right after the call.
- If you must return, you can at least give it a better name. Something like `startNewDataCreation(callback)`, where `callback` will be the observer you refer to.
- If you cannot change the implementation at all, a better alternative might be to check if the data has been created at regular intervals. That would at least guarantee correctness; `Thread.sleep(10000);` seems like a hack that may fail in adverse conditions.

Comment: Thanks. Its likely that the implementation cannot be changed. In that case, is it okay to continue using Thread.sleep or maybe use/create some code to check every few seconds that the data is created ?

Comment: I think it's much better to check if the data is created, because we are not leaving anything to chance, and are *guaranteed* to be correct

Answer (score 1):

Either use a testing framework that supports asynchronous tests like [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/) (it can be used with java) or block the call.

If the call adheres to the `CompletionStage` interface for example, you can:

```
@Test
public void doApiTesting() throws Exception
{
    framework.loginUser(User);
    framework.createNewData()
        .toCompletableFuture().get();
}
```

Btw, I hope you're not doing external calls to API's or database in your unit tests. If you are, they aren't unit tests ;)

Comment: Don't know the shortcuts for that. You could try to assign a variable of type `CompletionStage` to that expression and see if it complains. If it doesn't implement `CompletionStage` and it doesn't receive a callback why do you need to wait? It must be synchronous or return something that can be waited upon